# Resolve absolute paths with wildcards in Java 6

Tags: java, path, wildcard, glob

My problem is that I have a number of directories I have to look into programmatically, in Java. These directories all have the same pattern:

```
d:\a\b\c\??_????\d\
```

I cannot find a way to do this smartly. Any FileFilter (I use WildcardFileFilter) will need a base directory to look into, as they only works with listFiles(), yet in my case there is not base directory as my paths are absolute. I've unsuccessfully tried a few tricks from the Web and then I'm stuck. Your help will be greatly appreciated.[enter link description here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/WildcardFileFilter.html)

Comment: Do you have absolute path for each individual directory ?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I don't understand your question. All the directories I'm interested in have the same above pattern, therefore they are all absolute, yes. Was that your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try use listFilesAndDirs pointing to root folder or to d:\a\b\c.

Comment: I thought of that, but to do it I'd have to parse the path's string in order to detect where the glob part starts. It sounded pretty annoying to me and I was wondering whether a smarter way existed. That's for the "d:\a\b\c" option. You're talking about the root folder too: I like that. How do you get the root folder?

Comment: I think '/' works for all operating systems now mac, linux and win >= win7 but I am not sure.

Comment: Nah, I've tried it already. After the code `FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("d:/a/b/c/??_????/d/");
   File[] files = new File("/").listFiles(fileFilter);` is run, `files` is empty even if the directories do exist.